# Accessing the data from SQLalchemy query object?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am querying my database using the following command in python:

```
self.deleted_packages = model.Session.query(
            model.Package).filter_by(state=model.State.DELETED)
```

And I am accessing the above value in pkg as show below:

```
for pkg in self.deleted_packages:
```

The output in pkg is :

```
<Package id=563e0da3-6916-4158-bc9f-f11bf92d3240 
 name=asdacaasas 
 title=asdacaasas 
 version= url= author= author_email= maintainer= maintainer_email= notes= 
 license_id=cc-by 
 type=dataset
 owner_org=9b89900e-c4b8-413d-a8fe-edbe08641022 
 creator_user_id=30ad2d1c-f133-4458-9947-535e2718a898 
 metadata_created=2019-05-21 13:08:52.322015 
 metadata_modified=2019-05-21 13:08:59.946710 
 private=True 
 state=deleted 
 revision_id=5251e583-3a71-4189-8d4e-aaac8ac69927>
```

I just require the package id in a variable. And when I try to do the following:
p1=[x[0] for x in pkg]

I get the following error:

```
p1=[x[0] for x in pkg]
TypeError: 'Package' object is not iterable
```

Does someone know how can i store the value of just id : `563e0da3-6916-4158-bc9f-f11bf92d3240` in a variable from the above query result.?

Comment: what library / package are you using ? SQLAlchemy ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers , yes I am using SQLalchemy v1.3

Comment: @B.C can you please elaborate more on it?

Comment: @argg then have you searched the SQLAlchemy doc before posting here ? I'd be suprised if you didn't find the answer...

Comment: Done @brunodesthuilliers, but why did you downvote.?

Comment: because you are supposed to first try to solve the issue by yourself and explain your efforts in your question. IOW it falls under the "this question doesn't show any research effort" category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the docs for [SQLalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html) (I am getting this context from the comments).

There are a few examples examples that can highlight how you could get around your issue.

An example from the documentation linked in this answer (not relevant to your exact case!):

```
>>> for row in session.query(User, User.name).all():
...    print(row.User, row.name)
```

With the output being:

```
<User(name='ed', fullname='Ed Jones', nickname='eddie')> ed
<User(name='wendy', fullname='Wendy Williams', nickname='windy')> wendy
<User(name='mary', fullname='Mary Contrary', nickname='mary')> mary
<User(name='fred', fullname='Fred Flintstone', nickname='freddy')> fred
```

So in your case the `pkg` variable (an object of the `Package` class) *might be similar* to the `User` object in the example above and the `name` contents is accessed by `row.name`.

So your case might have something like `pkg.id`