# flask -- change output from response

Tags: python, json, flask, request, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask api I'm trying to make (it's new territory for me) and I'm unsatisfied with how the data is returned.

It works and connects to the database and returns data (yay) but it's a list of dictionaries (boo).

I would like reformat it so when it is called it appears different.

flask model:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse, abort, fields, marshal_with
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'postgres://postgres:[password]@127.0.0.1:5432/usagestats'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class StatsModel(db.Model):
    #added in from edit1
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__dict__[key]
    __tablename__ = "smogon_usage_stats"

    id_ = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    rank = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    pokemon = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    usage_pct = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    raw_usage = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    raw_pct = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    real = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    real_pct = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    dex = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    tier = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Stats(id = {id_}, rank = {rank}, pokemon = {pokemon}, usage_pct = {usage_pct}, raw_usage = {raw_usage}, raw_pct = {raw_pct}, real = {real}, real_pct = {real_pct})"

resource_fields = {
    'id_': fields.Integer,
    'rank': fields.Integer,
    'pokemon': fields.String,
    'usage_pct': fields.Float,
    'raw_usage': fields.Integer,
    'raw_pct': fields.Float,
    'real': fields.Integer,
    'real_pct': fields.Float,
    'dex': fields.Integer,
    'date': fields.String,
    'tier': fields.String
}

class Stats(Resource):
    @marshal_with(resource_fields)
    def get(self, date, tier):
        result = StatsModel.query.filter_by(date=date, tier=tier + "-1500").all()

        return result

api.add_resource(Stats, "/stats/<string:date>/<string:tier>-1500")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=3000, debug=True)
```

Which returns below when called:

```py
[
  {'id_': 669551, 'rank': 153, 'pokemon': 'snorunt', 'usage_pct': 0.07347, 'raw_usage': 104, 'raw_pct': 0.127, 'real': 96, 'real_pct': 0.148, 'dex': 361, 'date': '2020-04', 'tier': 'gen8lc-1500'}, 
  {'id_': 669552, 'rank': 154, 'pokemon': 'milcery', 'usage_pct': 0.0672, 'raw_usage': 108, 'raw_pct': 0.131, 'real': 87, 'real_pct': 0.134, 'dex': 868, 'date': '2020-04', 'tier': 'gen8lc-1500'}, 
  {'id_': 669553, 'rank': 156, 'pokemon': 'cosmog', 'usage_pct': 0.0199, 'raw_usage': 26, 'raw_pct': 0.032, 'real': 19, 'real_pct': 0.029, 'dex': 789, 'date': '2020-04', 'tier': 'gen8lc-1500'}
]
```

but I would like it to look like this:

```py
{
  "data": 
    'snorunt': {
      'id_': 669551, 'rank': 153, 'pokemon': 'snorunt', 'usage_pct': 0.07347, 'raw_usage': 104, 'raw_pct': 0.127, 'real': 96, 'real_pct': 0.148, 'dex': 361, 'date': '2020-04', 'tier': 'gen8lc-1500'}, 
    'milcery': {
      'id_': 669552, 'rank': 154, 'pokemon': 'milcery', 'usage_pct': 0.0672, 'raw_usage': 108, 'raw_pct': 0.131, 'real': 87, 'real_pct': 0.134, 'dex': 868, 'date': '2020-04', 'tier': 'gen8lc-1500'}, 
    'cosmog': {
      'id_': 669553, 'rank': 156, 'pokemon': 'cosmog', 'usage_pct': 0.0199, 'raw_usage': 26, 'raw_pct': 0.032, 'real': 19, 'real_pct': 0.029, 'dex': 789, 'date': '2020-04', 'tier': 'gen8lc-1500'
  }
}
```

I've tried manipulating `result` in the `Stats` class, but it throws an error (I've since taken it out, but it was an error of not being iterable). I can always change the data with my webapp code, I guess, but I'd rather have it packaged and ready to go.

### edit 1

so I found some solutions but nothing has quite worked yet.

To make the object subscriptable, I added this to the model:

```py
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__dict__[key]
    __tablename__ = "smogon_usage_stats"
```

and made the `Stats` class' get function return statement:

`return {"data": {x["pokemon"]: x for x in result}}`

but that only gave me a single output. which is I guess technically improvement. (also got the same result when trying the proposed answer below

### edit 2

I tried simplifying it if maybe I was missing something and stopped trying to be fancy with one line, and it's still giving me a single output. I've verified that `result` is a list with length `143`. But for some reason or other, I'm not getting the results I want, and I'm running out of airspace and ideas.

```py
class Stats(Resource):
    @marshal_with(resource_fields)
    def get(self, date, tier):
        result = StatsModel.query.filter_by(date=date, tier=tier + "-1500").all()
        resp = {"data":{}}
        for i in range(len(result)): 
            t = {result[i]["pokemon"]: result[i]}
            resp["data"].update(t)
        return resp
```

and that returns this when I do a request:

```py
{
'id_': 0, 
'rank': 0, 
'pokemon': None, 
'usage_pct': None, 
#... to save space but you get the idea
'tier': None
}
```

also, just to be sure, I did a `type()` check on the iterated objects, and they returned `<class '__main__.StatsModel'>`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but it worked like the way you wanted.

```py
class Stats(Resource):
    @marshal_with(resource_fields)
    def get(self, date, tier):
        result = StatsModel.query.filter_by(date=date, tier=tier + "-1500").all()

        return {"data": list(map(lambda x: {x['pokemon']: x}, result))}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I got an error `TypeError: 'StatsModel' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This will read each element from your result and save it to a dict. Then save this dict into another dict, as per your format:

```
class Stats(Resource):
    @marshal_with(resource_fields)
    def get(self, date, tier):
        dict1, dict2 = {}, {}
        #result = StatsModel.query.filter_by(date=date, tier=tier + "-1500").all()
        for x in StatsModel.query.filter_by(date=date, tier=tier + "-1500").all():
            dict1[x["pokemon"]] = x.__dict__
        dict2["data"] = dict1
        return dict2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still didn't work. I'm not sure what's going on. I've tested by printing dict[key] values and they print, so it is functioning like a dictionary. This was the output it gave me `{'id_': 0, 'rank': 0, 'pokemon': None, 'usage_pct': None, 'raw_usage': 0, 'raw_pct': None, 'real': 0, 'real_pct': None, 'dex': 0, 'date': None, 'tier': None}` and gave no errors.

Comment: Okay, can you paste the output you received while running the code I mentioned?

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was confusing, that was the was produced when I tried to use your solution.

Comment: Okay.  Can you tell what is the data type of result?  Try
`type(result)`

Comment: `type(result)` gave me `<class 'list'>` and each the `type` of each item in `result` is `<class '__main__.StatsModel'>`

Comment: I have edited the code a little bit. Can you try this? I did some digging around and found that in order to extract the data from the SQLAlchemy objects, you should directly use it in the for loop, instead of saving it and calling it again. Here is an example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56240694/13125348)

Comment: I tried it and got the same output as my first comment. However, I threw in a print statement to debug and got this: `{'data': {'goldeen': <StatsModel 669508>, 'vullaby': <StatsModel 669411>, 'onix': <StatsModel 669412>, 'timburr': <StatsModel 669413>}}`

Comment: Okay, try x.__dict__ . This will help to access the SQLAlchemy internal dict. I have edited the code above.

Comment: Sigh. That didn't work either. I tried hardcoding in the `dict` values even: `dict1[x["pokemon"]] = {'id_': x["id_"], 'rank': x["rank"], 'pokemon': x["pokemon"], 'usage_pct': x["usage_pct"], 'raw_usage': x["raw_usage"], 'raw_pct': x["raw_pct"], 'real': x["real"], 'real_pct': x["real_pct"], 'dex': x["dex"], 'date': x["date"], 'tier': x["tier"]}` and even that gave the same results.

Comment: `x.__dict__` printed: `{'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7fa5d616b310>, 'date': '2020-04', 'real_pct': 6.806, 'raw_pct': 6.328, 'raw_usage': 5200, 'pokemon': 'koffing', 'id_': 669434, 'tier': 'gen8lc-1500', 'dex': 109, 'real': 4429, 'usage_pct': 6.79894, 'rank': 26}`

Comment: I think this x.__dict__ thing works. You just need to remove the keys '_sa_instance_state' . Right?

Comment: One would have thought so. However, no luck after trying with list comprehension or with `.pop('_sa_insatnce_state')` or with `del`. I got the result: `TypeError: 'InstanceState' object is not subscriptable`. I've used both `x.pop` and `x.__dict__.pop` and the best case scenario is the empy `dict` result in the top comment. it feels like one of those things where the juice isn't worth the squeeze.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Flask-RESTful, but this seems like a simple data-transformation problem.

In an interactive Python shell:

```py
>>> rowList = [
...   {'id_': 669551, 'rank': 153, 'pokemon': 'snorunt', 'usage_pct': 0.07347, 'raw_usage': 104, 'raw_pct': 0.127, 'real': 96, 'real_pct': 0.148, 'dex': 361, 'date': '2020-04', 'tier': 'gen8lc-1500'}, 
...   {'id_': 669552, 'rank': 154, 'pokemon': 'milcery', 'usage_pct': 0.0672, 'raw_usage': 108, 'raw_pct': 0.131, 'real': 87, 'real_pct': 0.134, 'dex': 868, 'date': '2020-04', 'tier': 'gen8lc-1500'}, 
...   {'id_': 669553, 'rank': 156, 'pokemon': 'cosmog', 'usage_pct': 0.0199, 'raw_usage': 26, 'raw_pct': 0.032, 'real': 19, 'real_pct': 0.029, 'dex': 789, 'date': '2020-04', 'tier': 'gen8lc-1500'}
... ]
>>> 
>>> transformed = {"data": {row['pokemon']: row for row in rowList}}
>>> 
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(transformed)
{'data': {'cosmog': {'date': '2020-04',
                     'dex': 789,
                     'id_': 669553,
                     'pokemon': 'cosmog',
                     'rank': 156,
                     'raw_pct': 0.032,
                     'raw_usage': 26,
                     'real': 19,
                     'real_pct': 0.029,
                     'tier': 'gen8lc-1500',
                     'usage_pct': 0.0199},
          'milcery': {'date': '2020-04',
                      'dex': 868,
                      'id_': 669552,
                      'pokemon': 'milcery',
                      'rank': 154,
                      'raw_pct': 0.131,
                      'raw_usage': 108,
                      'real': 87,
                      'real_pct': 0.134,
                      'tier': 'gen8lc-1500',
                      'usage_pct': 0.0672},
          'snorunt': {'date': '2020-04',
                      'dex': 361,
                      'id_': 669551,
                      'pokemon': 'snorunt',
                      'rank': 153,
                      'raw_pct': 0.127,
                      'raw_usage': 104,
                      'real': 96,
                      'real_pct': 0.148,
                      'tier': 'gen8lc-1500',
                      'usage_pct': 0.07347}}}
>>>
```

Unless I'm missing something, it appears that `transformed` is exactly what you're looking for. (What am I missing?)

It could be, of course, that `result` in your code is not a `list`, while `rowList` above is. In that case, consider converting it to a list (and converting contained records to dicts) first.

Answer (score 0):

For simply change between

```py
[
    {"id_": 669551, "rank": 153, "pokemon": "snorunt", "usage_pct": 0.07347, 
     "raw_usage": 104, "raw_pct": 0.127, "real": 96, "real_pct": 0.148, 
     "dex": 361, "date": "2020-04", "tier": "gen8lc-1500"},
    {"id_": 669552, "rank": 154, "pokemon": "milcery", "usage_pct": 0.0672,
     "raw_usage": 108, "raw_pct": 0.131, "real": 87, "real_pct": 0.134,
     "dex": 868, "date": "2020-04", "tier": "gen8lc-1500"},
    {"id_": 669553, "rank": 156, "pokemon": "cosmog", "usage_pct": 0.0199, 
     "raw_usage": 26, "raw_pct": 0.032, "real": 19, "real_pct": 0.029, 
     "dex": 789, "date": "2020-04", "tier": "gen8lc-1500"}
]
```

and

```py
{"data": {
    "snorunt": {
        "id_": 669551, "rank": 153, "pokemon": "snorunt", "usage_pct": 0.07347,
        "raw_usage": 104, "raw_pct": 0.127, "real": 96, "real_pct": 0.148, 
        "dex": 361, "date": "2020-04", "tier": "gen8lc-1500"},
    "milcery": {
        "id_": 669552, "rank": 154, "pokemon": "milcery", "usage_pct": 0.0672, 
        "raw_usage": 108, "raw_pct": 0.131, "real": 87, "real_pct": 0.134,
        "dex": 868, "date": "2020-04", "tier": "gen8lc-1500"},
    "cosmog": {
        "id_": 669553, "rank": 156, "pokemon": "cosmog", "usage_pct": 0.0199, 
        "raw_usage": 26, "raw_pct": 0.032, "real": 19, "real_pct": 0.029, 
        "dex": 789, "date": "2020-04", "tier": "gen8lc-1500"
    }
}}
```

Try simply

```py
new_result = {"data": {}}
for item in dictionary:
    new_result["data"][item["pokemon"]] = item
```

where `dictionary` is the first one and `new_result` the second one.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Stats(Resource):
@marshal_with(resource_fields)
def get(self, date, tier):
    data_dict, result = {}, {}
    for item in StatsModel.query.filter_by(date=date, tier=tier + "-1500").all():
        data_dict[item["pokemon"]] = item
    result["data"] = data_dict
    return result
```